# where are Firefox personas images saved?

Tags: windows, firefox, personas

Is it possible to retrieve the full image that the Persona use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Windows 7 available to me at the moment I am typing this, but try clicking the start button, and selecting "run". Then enter `%APPDATA%` (without the arrows). It should load a screen with all of your PCs programs.

Then click "Mozilla", then "Firefox", and then "profiles". Your profile name will probably be different than mine, but it was the only folder in my "profiles" folder. Click on whichever profile you are using (or if it is like mine and you just have one profile, pick that folder). Then select the "persona" folder, and then the "cache" folder. That is where you will find the currently used persona images actually, they are inside another folder which has whatever the name of that persona is).

It only stores the current one though, so if you want that image, copy it to another location to save it, and then load your next persona. That will update the "cache" folder with those images, so they too can be copied.

I also added this info as an edit to an above question/answer with a little more detail.

Answer (score 6):

Firefox 3.6 Personas, AKA *Lightweight Themes*, are not stored on the computer. They are loaded from the web each time the browser is loaded. All of the URLs are stored in the `about:config` preferences editor under `lightweightThemes.usedThemes`.

Let's assume you just installed the [Dark Fox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dark-fox-18066/) persona. It would then look like this in the `about:config` editor:

Preference Name: **`lightweightThemes.usedThemes`**
Status: **`user set`**
Type: **`string`**
Value:

```
[{"id":"18066","name":"Dark Fox","headerURL":"https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addons/18066/1232849758499.jpg?1241547734","footerURL":"https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addons/18066/1232849758500.jpg?1241547734","textcolor":"#ffffff","accentcolor":"#000000","iconURL":"https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addons/18066/preview_small.jpg?1241547734","previewURL":"https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addons/18066/preview_large.jpg?1241547734","author":"randomaster","description":"My dark version of the Firefox logo.","updateURL":"https://versioncheck.addons.mozilla.org/en-US/themes/update-check/18066","version":"1.0","updateDate":1495495021492,"installDate":1495495021492}]
```

If you take a look at the value, you will see that we're dealing with the JSON format here. Run it through a [JSON beautifier](https://duck.co/ia/view/json_validator) and you will get the following result.

```json
[
    {
        "id": "18066",
        "name": "Dark Fox",
        "headerURL": "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addons/18066/1232849758499.jpg?1241547734",
        "footerURL": "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addons/18066/1232849758500.jpg?1241547734",
        "textcolor": "#ffffff",
        "accentcolor": "#000000",
        "iconURL": "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addons/18066/preview_small.jpg?1241547734",
        "previewURL": "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addons/18066/preview_large.jpg?1241547734",
        "author": "randomaster",
        "description": "My dark version of the Firefox logo.",
        "updateURL": "https://versioncheck.addons.mozilla.org/en-US/themes/update-check/18066",
        "version": "1.0",
        "updateDate": 1495495021492,
        "installDate": 1495495021492
    }
]
```

This way we can carefully examine what a Firefox persona consists of. `id` is self-explanatory as well as the `name`.

`headerURL` is the URL of the actual image being used in the Firefox header located [here](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addons/18066/1232849758499.jpg?1241547734). `footerURL` is the URL of the image being used as Firefox [footer bar](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addons/18066/1232849758500.jpg?1241547734).

The `textcolor` is set to the hexadecimal value `#ffffff` which is the color white and the `accentcolor` is set to the hexadecimal value `#000000` which translates to the color black and is basically the font outline color.

Next we have `iconURL` which specifies the URL of the *Dark Fox* Addon [icon](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addons/18066/preview_small.jpg?1241547734) which is shown under *Tools > Add-ons > Appearance*. The next string `previewURL` shows us the location of the preview image, which is shown when you [look up Firefox Personas](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/themes/) or visit the [corresponding Persona page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dark-fox-18066/). In this case, that preview image looks like [this](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addons/18066/preview_large.jpg?1241547734). The value of the `author` string is the name of the author and the value of the `description` string is the description text which can be observed [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dark-fox-18066/).

I am not exactly sure what the value of `updateURL` represents, but we can see its [content](https://versioncheck.addons.mozilla.org/en-US/themes/update-check/18066) and therefore conclude it's yet again in a JSON format and most likely used for update checks. The value 1.0 tells us the `version` of the *Dark Fox* Persona. Next up we have the value 1495495021492 of the `updateDate` string and 1495495021492 showing us the value of `installDate`.

See the [Mozilla Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Themes) for more information about lightweight themes.