# For Firefox Quantum (v70) where can I find the theme/persona background image?

Tags: firefox, json, about-config

Is there a way to get the background image for a Firefox theme downloaded from the Mozilla add-on website? Mainly I want the image for this theme:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-CA/firefox/addon/warrior-world-of-warcraft/

Previous threads such as this one:
[where are Firefox personas images saved?](https://superuser.com/questions/115369/where-are-firefox-personas-images-saved) don't help, as the "lightweight theme" entry in about:config is empty for me (shows []). I think the above theme is not lightweight.

I tried going to APPDATA/Roaming -> Mozilla -> Firefox -> Profiles folder but nothing inside there is an image file.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you mean the image shown in tittlebar in Firefox window? Then you can download the extension and extract the image from it. For example, download [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/2538813/warrior_world_of_warcraft-2.0-an+fx.xpi), extract the PNG file with 7zip.

Comment: For anyone else in the future, the way to download a firefox theme as an .xpi file is right click the Install button and select "Save Link As". These .xpi files can then be opened using WinRAR or 7zip. 

Thank you @Biswapriyo for the help, I got the PNG now! Appreciate it. 

If anyone can tell me how to mark this question as solved, would help a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download the title-bar image of any Firefox add-on theme, go to the page of the theme. Ensure it is **not** already installed in your browser.

1. Right-click the "Install" blue button on the page, and select the "Save Link As" option.
2. This should download a .xpi file, which can be opened and extracted using software such as WinRAR or 7Zip.
3. After extracting the files, the content should include a PNG image which will be the title-bar header image of the Firefox add-on theme.

All done! This is how you get the image of any theme in Firefox.

This answer was provided by @Biswapriyo.